# How to number a figure using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

For the general plot in R, `legend` is used to number a figure.

```
set.seed(100)
Mydata=rnorm(65)
Year=1950:2014
plot(x=Year,y=Mydata,type = "l")
legend("topleft","(a)",bty = "n")
```

I wonder how we can do the same thing using ggplot2. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: you are looking for geom_text or geom_label.  Here is a link to [the documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_text.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using grid it can be done independently of the data:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Year, Mydata, geom = "line")

library(grid)
grid.text("(a)", 0.15, 0.85)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `grid.text` is a smart way to number the figure as it requires only the percentage of the (a). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

As of version 2.2.0, `ggplot2` allows to plot subtitles and captions which can be utilized for this purpose.

### subtitle (top left)

```
# create data frame as required by ggplot2
mydf <- data.frame(Year, Mydata)

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mydf, aes(Year, Mydata)) + 
  geom_line()

# plot subtitle (top left)
p + labs(subtitle = "(a)")
```

[image]

### caption (bottom right)

```
# plot caption (bottom right)
p + labs(caption = "(a)")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is a good way, but some papers prefer the "(a)" to be in the figure area, like what I have showed in the post.

Answer (score 2):

A way with `annotate`:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(100)
Mydata=rnorm(65)
Year=1950:2014
data <- data.frame(Mydata = Mydata, Year = Year)

#plot
ggplot(data, aes(Year, Mydata)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  annotate('text', x = 1960, y = 2, label = '(a)')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this without specifying the **data coordinates** for the position of the label -- either something like "topleft" or percentage values of the (x,y) location?  It becomes difficult when you have two side-by-side plots with different scales, and want to label them (a), (b) in about the same places in each plot.

Comment: @user101089 I think the other answer takes care of that.